# Remove single quotes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string like `(''acc','xyz'')`, I need the output as `('acc','xyz')`.

What will be the query or any regular expression to remove extra quotes.?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe you only need a `replace`

Comment: Where do you have that string - in a table column? In a PL/SQL variable? Coming from some external source? Are the parentheses actually part of the string or were they just added for effect? Come context would be useful, along with some idea of what you've tried and why that didn't work for you.

Comment: it's value is coming from a variable. I tried replace but didn't work. I will use select expression from dual to select the values and pass it into a IN statement.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code, to help people in helping you. Also, what do you mean with "replace didn't work"? Are you having an error? an unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [REPLACE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm):

```
replace(q'[(''acc','xyz'')]', q'['']',q'[']')
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abb5d3/1

```
SELECT replace(q'[(''acc','xyz'')]', q'['']',q'[']')
FROM dual;

| REPLACE(Q'[(''ACC','XYZ'')]',Q'['']',Q'[']') |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                ('acc','xyz') |
```

Answer (score 1):

If that *string* always looks like you described, then replace two consecutive single quotes (CHR(39)) with a single one, such as

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select q'[(''acc','xyz'')]' from dual)
  3  select col,
  4    replace(col, chr(39)||chr(39), chr(39)) result
  5  from test;

COL             RESULT
--------------- ---------------
(''acc','xyz'') ('acc','xyz')

SQL>
```

Why CHR(39)? Because this: `replace(col, '''''', '''')` is difficult to read, and this: `replace(col, q'['']', q'[']')` looks *stupid*, but - use any of these (or *invent* your own way).

Comment: I agree that the `q` quoting mechanism looks strange in this case. But, while writing dynamic blocks, it truly saves you from a lot of pain stuffing those dreaded quotes.

Comment: Yes, @Kaushik. If you have a look at line #2 in my query, you'll see that I used the `q` quoting mechanism as it did NOT look stupid in that case :)